# Sequence of functions: Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

For each of the following, give an example of a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converges to f

A. uniformly but not in the mean square sense.

B. in the mean square sense but pointwise nowhere.

I know that for part A the domain of the function cannot be bounded but other then that I'm not sure how to go about the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hint A.

Set  $f_n(x) = g(n)1_{[0,n]}$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Choose $g(n)$ such that $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$, but $\int_0^\infty |f_n(x)|^2\, dx \to L \neq 0$.

Comment: All you've done is repeat the problem I stated.  Nothing in your answer helps me find a $f_n(x)$

Comment: Actually I did not repeat the problem statement. I gave more structure for you to find an answer without giving it away. Now you are looking for $f_n$ that is constant over compact support. So try $g(n) = 1/\sqrt{n}$.